# group correlate items in python list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists of the following form:

```
list = [ [['item1'], ['property1','property2','property3']], [['item2'],['property1', 'property4']], ..., [['itemN'],['property5']]]
```

I want to construct another list of lists with all the above items grouped together with those they share at least one property with. E.g.:

```
new_list = [['item1','item2'], .., ['itemN']]
```

Note that items should be grouped together even if they share properties indirectly. If e.g. item1 has a common property with item2 that has a common property with item3 and item1 does not share any properties with item3 they should be still all grouped together.

My try has been with an added boolean to the original list (so that I do not re-iterate if not needed) and with the function below:

```
list = [ [['item1'], ['property1','property2','property3'], True], [['item2'],['property1', 'property4'], True], [['itemN'],['property5'], True]]

def group_correlates(list):
    result = []
    for i, entry in enumerate(list):
        correlates = []
        items = entry[0]
        properties = entry[1]
        if entry[2]: # if not already grouped (True)
            correlates.append(items)
        for j, other_entry in enumerate(list):
            flag = other_entry[2]
            if not i == j:
                if flag:
                    other_properties = other_entry[1]
                    other_items = other_entry[0]
                    for property in properties:
                        if property in other_properties:
                            other_entry[2] = False # do not visit again
                            correlates.append(other_items)
                            result.append(correlates)
    return result
```

but I get this:

```
[[['item1'], ['item2']], [['item1']]]
```

An even if I could do it this way, I am sure there is a much more elegant way to accomplish the same

Comment: why you don't use dictionary for that?

Comment: "grouped together with those they share properties", you mean, share ALL propreties or at least one?

Comment: at least one, i will edit it now

Comment: @KacperWolkowski this is a simplified example, in my actual code each items are also lists and possibly list of lists.

Comment: @MarinosK You mean your list is arbitrarily nested. If so, I'm not sure what you want your output to even be.

Comment: Are 'itemN' and 'propertyN' always string?

Comment: @ChristianDean, No it's not arbitrarily nested. each item and each property will always be lists of one or two dimensions. I can work it out from there if I have a working example.

Comment: @RodrigoNey No, but if I have an example that works with strings I can work it out from there myself.

Comment: The output are lists of 2 elements? imagine if item 1,2 and 3 share the same propertyN. The output should be what? [[item1,item2,item3]] or [[item1,item2],  [item1,item3], [item2,item3] ] ?

Comment: This needs to be much better defined.  For instance, given `[[item1], [p1, p2]], [[item2], [p2, p3]], [[item3], [p3]] ... do we combine the three items, even though `item1` and `item3` have no properties in common?  If so, then the algorithm you're facing is connectivity of a bipartite graph.

Comment: @Prune yes, they should be combined, I will look into bipartite graphs, thanks.

Comment: "Bipartite" is just nomenclature; I don't think it will help the solution much.  The main point is that you're finding sub-graphs that are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your list to a dictionary as mentioned.

```
list1 = [ [['item1'], ['property1','property2','property3']], 
          [['item2'], ['property1', 'property4']],
          [['item3'], ['property5', 'property6']]
        ]

dict1 = {item[0][0]: item[1] for item in list1}
```

Then:

```
new_list = []

for key in dict1:
    target = dict1[key]
    for k, v in dict1.items():
        if k != key and len(set(target).intersection(set(v))) != 0:
            new_list.append([key, k])
    new_list = [sorted(i) for i in new_list] # sort sublists
    new_list = [list(t) for t in set(map(tuple, new_list))] # remove dupes

flat = [item for sublist in new_list for item in sublist] # flatten list
unique = list(set(dict1.keys()).difference(set(flat)))
new_list.append(unique) # add unique keys

new_list
Out[76]: [['item1', 'item2'], ['item3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a `dict` then using `groupby` from `itertools` module ?

This is an example of how you can do it:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [[['item1'], ['property1','property2','property3']], [['item2'],['property1', 'property4']], [['itemN'],['property5']]]

aa = {}
for k, v in data:
    for j in v:
        try:
            aa[j] += k
        except KeyError:
            aa[j] = k


new_list = [k for k,_ in groupby(sorted(aa.values()), lambda x: x)]
print(new_list)
```

Or, you can use `defaultdict` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

data = [[['item1'], ['property1','property2','property3']], [['item2'],['property1', 'property4']], [['itemN'],['property5']]]

bb = defaultdict(None)

for k, v in data:
    for j in v:
        bb[j] = k


new_list = [k for k,_ in groupby(sorted(bb.values()), lambda x: x)]
print(new_list)
```

Both will output:

```
[['item1', 'item2'], ['item2'], ['itemN']]
```

Answer (score 0):

"Bipartite" is mainly nomenclature.  The main point is that you're finding sub-graphs that are connected.

Put all of your nested lists into an "open" list ... you need to process everything in this list.  When it's empty, you're done.
Start a new list of sub-graphs -- this is the "list of lists" you mentioned.

Initialize an item list and a properties list to empty lists.

Pick an item and put it into a sub-graph list.  Now, alternate between properties and items until nothing gets added:

1. For each new item you just added (only that initial one the first time), add (to the properties list) all properties of that item.  Keep a list of which properties are new to the properties list.
2. Delete those items (and their properties) from your "open" list.
3. For each property just added, add (to the items list) each item that has that property.  Keep a list of the items just added.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until nothing new is added.

At this point, the items list and properties list described a closed sub-graph.  Add the pair to your master list of sub-graphs.

Go back, reset your items and properties lists to empty lists, and start with a new initial item.  Continue this until you've exhausted all items.  The "open" list is now empty; all items and properties are now represented in the sub-graphs list.